# Updating database with state values in React

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a React app with Django as backend. I have a web page with input fields related to an invoice like:

- Customer Name
- Address
- Contact No.
- Product Name
- Product Qty
- Product Rate
- ...

I want some help regarding the common practices followed to save the data entered and updated in these fields. My intention is to auto save (i.e. without the user having to press 'Save' button) the data entered or updated in these fields. Currently, the aim is to deploy it local (offline) only, so I am not worried about internet connection for the API requests.
Currently, I can only think of using `onBlur` on every field and call a handler to save the change to the database.
I would really appreciate some guidelines on how to deal with this.

(PS: I have tried my best to make this a question, not a discussion. If this is still not the case, kindly mention what am I supposed to do before you downvote)

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Answer (score 1):

The `onChange` [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) can be leveraged to capture changes in the values of input elements.

[`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can be used to persist data.

See below for a rough example of the two concepts combined.

```
// Input Field.
<input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}/>

// Handle Change.
handleChange = event => {
  const {value} = event.target
  window.localStorage.setItem('value', value) // Persist Data Locally.
  this.setState({value}) // Update State.
}
```